# Sample Contracts for Testing Static Analysis Tools

Tags: contract-debugging, vulnerability, tools

I have to analyse some static Analysis tools against  [well documented vulnerabilities](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-100). My questions are ;

1. Can we use the provided sample contracts (in above link) directly or not ?
2. If not, then where should I can find such **real vulnerable contracts**?
3. If i want to download previously attacked smart contracts (i.e. DAO, parity, etc.), are they still available to test by open source static tools or not ?
4. The list of vulnerabilities in above link is completed/updated or not , in term of exposed/known vulnerabilities till today?

Any useful s**uggestion toward performing and contributing in static analysis domain** , will be appreciated !

Comment: There are several separated questions here, each of which sounds like something which requires quite a bit of Googling. You're asking for a useful suggestion, so this is essentially my suggestion to you - most of the information that you're asking for can be found on Google, so Google each one of those issues, gather most of the information and come back with a (single) more specific question for each issue. I am suggesting this, because you are otherwise asking others to do the preliminary research described above for you.

Comment: thanks, for suggestion... Although i have google little bit.. again i will try to find some more information... BTW. I think, some of questions can be answered directly without doing preliminary research (if someone has knowledge)...